# Angular: App Component not detecting change of Child Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm building a shopping cart, and everything is working fine except when the website first load, if the person doesn't have a shopping cart saved, they have to click add to cart before one is made. The problem is, my app.component doesn't realize that local storage is updated until the page is refreshed. I've been working on this for 3 days and cant seem to figure it out. I tried to refresh the page after the button is clicked, but that resulted in some of my functions not being called at all. I read about subjects and behavior variables. It didn't seem to correspond with what it is I feel I need. To my understanding, a subject or behavior variable requires subscribing to an observable, but I don't need to subscribe to anything in this instance. I just need to know when local storage is updated in real time. The only relevant piece of code is the code in app.component.ts because it is the code that is manipulating the cart total and count. I added the other piece of code just in case that may be a problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

app.component.ts

```
id: localStorage.getItem('cartId');

        if(this.id){
         this.dbList =  db.list('/shopping-carts/' + this.id).valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
            this.dbTotal = items[items.length - 1];
            this.dbCartCount = items.length - 2;
            console.log('total and cart count updated...');
          });

        }
```

clotheslist.component.ts

```
addToCart(product, price){
  let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');

  if(!cartId){
    this.cartService.create().then(result => {
      localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
      this.cartService.pushProductToCart(product, price);
      this.cartService.cartTotal(price);
    });
  //add product to cart
  } else {
  this.cartService.pushProductToCart(product, price);
  this.cartService.cartTotal(price);
  }
}
```

Comment: nb: you should not put the logic of your component in the constructor but in the ngOnInit function.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Can you tell me why this is? @Ploppy

Comment: Angular has complex life cycles and sometimes, the code in the constructor might throw an error. Basically you should not put code that affect the template in the constructor.

Comment: alright thanks, good to know. I refactored it

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making an event bus implemented as an Angular service. You would use the RxJs Subject for this.

AppEventService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppEventService {
  private eventBus: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  public events: Observable<string> = this.eventBus.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  publishEvent(eventName: string) {
    this.eventBus.next(eventName);
  }
}
```

clothes-list.component.ts

```
addToCart(product, price){
  let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');

  if(!cartId){
    this.cartService.create().then(result => {
      localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
      this.cartService.pushProductToCart(product, price);
      this.cartService.cartTotal(price);
      //add product to cart
      this.eventsService.publishEvent('cart-updated');
    });
  } else {
  this.cartService.pushProductToCart(product, price);
  this.cartService.cartTotal(price);
  }
}
```

Finally, in app.component.ts:

```
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(..., private eventsService: AppEventsService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.eventsService.events
        .filter(eventName => eventName === 'cart-updated')
        .subscribe(this.handleCartChange.bind(this));
   }

   handleCartChange() {
      // execute your logic to update the cart total and item count here
   }
}
```

Notice that you likely have to use the [JS bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function when providing the observer (subscribe) to retain the context to the component class instance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a possible solution. Question, shouldn't the eventsBus/events property be an array instead of a string? it's throwing an error that filter does not exist on observable string.

Comment: if it helps, this is my imported rxjs import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators'